# Not sure why sparkjava webservice is throwing 400 error on encoded date

Tags: spark-java

I am passing this URL:

```
"http://localhost:8080/services/getWeeksFromDate/2%2F25%2F2020"
```

and it's coming up with this error:

## HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

Type Status Report

Message Invalid URI: noSlash

Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a
client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

#### Apache Tomcat/9.0.7

Even though I'm URL Encoding the date, it's never making it to the method.

If I pass "Hello" instead of the encoded date above, it works OK.

In the actual method, I'm just trying to return the string passed in -- no processing while I try to figure this out.

Nothing helpful in the Tomcat log. Can't debug since this happens outside method code.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This seems due to Tomcat decoding slash characters before they even reach Spark, as a security measure.

You can disable this behavior by setting system property `org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH` to `true` (e.g through Tomcat's `catalina.properties`).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. But doing that seems to send in / characters for the date pieces. So, if I pass in "2" for the date, I get to the method and get an expected error. But, if I pass in "2%2F25%2F2020" for the date, I get a 404 error -- meaning, I think, that the "/" are somehow back and it's looking for a method that does not exist.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like Tomcat still decodes those before passing the URI to Spark. Then I see 2 choices: you can either over-encode the URI - translate `%` characters to `%25`, e.g `2%252F25%252F2020` - or map your service in Spark as `/services/getWeeksFromDate/:month/:day/:year`. I managed to get both work with Tomcat 9 and Spark 2.9.

Comment: Thanks. What I ended up doing, short of forcing the user to use ISO 8601 format, was to use Base64Encoding and just forget about UrlEncoding with Tomcat. Your ideas are great, though, and I will keep them in mind. Thanks again.